# Is there a way to retain responsive number of columns piping through less?

Tags: bash, shell, less-unix

I have a simple script

```
echo "Some Text"
echo " "
compgen -c a | sort | uniq | column
echo " "
```

This line set is repeated for each letter of the alphabet (not set in a loop) in `1stscript.sh`.

I have a second `lessscript.sh`.

```
1stscript.sh | less
```

Running `1stscript.sh` by itself fills the entire width of my terminal emulator:

But running `lessscript.sh` or `1stscript.sh | less` directly only uses  about 1/3 of my terminal emulator's width:

```
aa-exec         apropos         atrm
ab              apt             aubrsync
aclocal         apt-cache       aubusy
```

I have tried commenting out set text length lines. I have tried flags with `column` such as `t` and `x` to no avail.

How can I make it adapt to my terminal width in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

`column` will try to find the size of the terminal it's writing to, but if it's writing to a pipe (which has no inherent width), it defaults to 80.

The program `tput` does the same, but in addition to output, it checks stdin, stderr, and the session TTY. You can therefore use that to determine the column count for `column`:

```
echo "Some Text"
echo " "
compgen -c a | sort | uniq | column -c "$(tput cols)"
echo " "
```